# PostgreSQL Aggregate function select 2 corresponding fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sub query:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        MAX(testresult."testdate") AS beforeresult,
        testschedule."test_id",
        testschedule."asset_id",
        testschedule."testdate" AS testdate,
        testschedule."testresult_id" as scheduleresult_id                                        
    FROM
        "public"."testresult" testresult 
        INNER JOIN "public"."testschedule" testschedule 
            ON testschedule."asset_id" = testresult."asset_id" 
            AND testschedule."test_id" = testresult."test_id" 
    WHERE
        "testresult"."client_id" = 25368272
        AND testresult."testdate" < testschedule."mintolerancedate"
        AND testschedule."testdate" > '2016-10-01' 
        AND testschedule."testdate" < '2016-10-20'
    GROUP BY
        testschedule."asset_id", 
        testschedule."test_id", 
        testschedule."testdate", 
        testschedule."testresult_id" 
    ORDER BY MAX(testresult."testdate")
) lasttr
    ON "testschedule"."asset_id" = lasttr."asset_id"
    AND "testschedule"."test_id" = lasttr."test_id"
    AND testschedule."testdate" = lasttr.testdate
```

This gives me the correct testdate.  However, I also need the testschedule."testresult_id" that corresponds with the date.  Is there a way to select this from the above query?

Answer (score 0):

You can fiddle with window functions or in the most recent versions, do a left lateral join:

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
(SELECT ts."test_id", ts."asset_id", ts."testdate" AS testdate, ts."testresult_id" as scheduleresult_id,
        tr.*
 FROM "public"."testresult" tr INNER JOIN
      "public"."testschedule" ts
      ON ts."asset_id" = tr."asset_id" and ts."test_id" = tr."test_id" 
 WHERE tr."client_id" = 25368272 AND
       tr."testdate" < ts."mintolerancedate" AND
       ts."testdate" > '2016-10-01' and ts."testdate" < '2016-10-20' AND
       "testschedule"."asset_id" = ts."asset_id" AND
       "testschedule"."test_id" = ts."test_id"
 ORDER BY tr."testdate" DESC
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
) lasttr
```

A lateral join is like a correlated subquery in the `FROM` clause.  You can return as many columns as you like.  There is no `ON` clause because the join conditions are in the subquery's `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I'm still not getting the testschedule."testresult_id" field.  Basically it needs to somehow be joined to the MAX aggregate function for testdate, but I can't seem to make that work- my guess is it's something simple I'm overlooking.

Comment: You don't need another join.  The lateral join should do what you want.

Comment: So I'm adding "and" before each of these lines: "testschedule"."asset_id" = ts."asset_id"
       "testschedule"."test_id" = ts."test_id" and then when I run this, even when adding the group by clause I get a "syntax error at end of input".  If I add the "ON" clause, then it runs, but doesn't give me the result for each group.